# Is there any way to set field resolved in package-lock.json to empty

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-package, package-lock.json

In npm package-lock.json, I found the field of "resolved".
Is there any way to set it to empty.

I created local npm repository for stg and prd env respectively,
before building step, can I execute the command like below to determine which repository should be used.

npm config set @myco:registry http://stg.example.com

or

npm config set @myco:registry http://prd.example.com